# How to specify region name in AWS S3 Java API?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am using AWS Java API for S3. The access key, secret key, bucket name, and region name are all provided to my application as environment variables.

I am not sure how to set the region name...I'm currently getting the `AmazonS3Client`

```
return new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey))
```

Can someone please tell me how to set the region name?

Comment: Are you talking about AWS in general? Or S3 in specific? Also, do you want to change the region of an existing bucket or create a new bucket in some other region?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that if you have the region as a string, you can do this:

```
Regions regions = Regions.fromName('us-west-1');
```

And you can create a credentials provider in a variety of ways, including this:

```
AWSStaticCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
        new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY));
```

and then (for whatever builder you're doing), you can do this:

```
AmazonSNS snsClient = AmazonSNSClientBuilder.standard()
    .withRegion(region)
    .withCredentials(credentialsProvider)
    .build();
```

Comment: I am using this to upload objects to S3. Can I do: `AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey); Regions region = Region.fromName("us-west-1"); s3Client.setRegion(regions); s3Client.putObject("bucketname", "somefilename.txt", is, meta); ` ? Is there a better way to do it since `setRegion` on `AmazonS3Client` is deprecated.

Comment: Ask him why my edit was not approved. It was effing perfect @Anthony.

Comment: In my case I've had to use static: `Region.getRegion("eu-west-1")`, as `Regions.fromName("eu-west-1")` returns `Regions` instead of required `Region`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by `client.setRegion(region)` something like:

`AmazonS3Client client = 
new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey));
client.setRegion(region);
return client;`

Alternatively, `new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey))` picks the Region information from the following, if you haven't provided (it tries searching from 1 to 3) :

1.) EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider()

2.) SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider()

3.) EC2 instance

But this method is deprecated now, you should use now:

`AmazonS3 amazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                      .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
                      .build();`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the AWS code Catalog. There are many examples of doing this:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/java/example_code/s3/src/main/java/aws/example/s3

Hope this helps